# Closures in C#, necessary or not?

Tags: c#, closure

I've written JavaScript for a while, but lately I've been writing a lot of C#.  I wanted to write a method that could take the column name of a `DataTable` and return an average for those values.  Having never written closures in C#, but being comfortable with them in JavaScript, I came up with this:

```
public static double GetColumnAverage(DataTable dt,string columnName)
{
    Func<DataTable, double> getAverage = (t) => t.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
                                                                        .Average(x => x.Field<dynamic>(columnName));
    bool isNumeric = true;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var type = row[columnName].GetType();
        //not all numeric data types, but close enough for this
        isNumeric = type == typeof(int) || type == typeof(double) || type == typeof(float) || type == typeof(uint)
            || type == typeof(byte);
        if (isNumeric ==false)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    return getAverage(dt);
}
```

From this I learned that the parameters passed to an inner delegate are matched to the outer delegate, so Intellisense picked up the `t` parameter as a DataTable (not sure about implications, but neat).  Cool.  My initial thought was to create a private helper method `IsNumeric` that would return a bool if the value in the DataRow was something we could average.

I know that I could probably improve this a little, but I'm wondering if there's any practical reason to using a closure here, or if there are any potential pitfalls that might make it a bad idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend reading [this article](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/) by Eric Lippert

You'll definitally want an extension method for this... let me hit the google real quick.... Using some inspired code from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749966/c-sharp-how-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-a-number/1750093) I wrote this.

```
static class Extensions
{
    private const HashSet<Type> NumericTypes = new HashSet<Type> 
        {typeof(decimal), typeof(byte), typeof(sbyte), typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
        typeof(int),typeof(uint), typeof(long), typeof(ulong), typeof(float), typeof(double)};

    /// <summary>Determines whether the specified object is numeric.</summary>
    public static bool IsNumeric(this object obj) { return NumericTypes.Contains(obj.GetType()); }
}
```

Now in your code you can just say

```
if(!row[columnName].IsNumeric())
    throw new Exception();
```

However, now I will review your code in general.

1. You should not throw `Exception`, you should always be specific with your exception throwing. In this case I probably would throw an `ArgumentException`, but really this seems like a specific case where you should define your own.
2. I'm a bit confused by your declaring `isNumeric` outside the loop, when you don't use it outside that scope.
3. instead of saying `if (isNumeric == false)` just say `if(!isNumeric)`
4. I don't see why you nested this function inside your loop. its not taking full advantage of the fact that it is nested, and could just aswell be a function outside. Plus why declare it if you might be throwing an exception.. might as well wait. And while you're waiting, lets just take this one liner and make it a statement instead. (My thoughts jumped around there a bit)

In the end your code could just look like.

```
public static double GetColumnAverage(DataTable dt, string columnName)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        if (!row[columnName].IsNumeric())
            throw new ArgumentException("-Something meaningful here-");
    return dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x[columnName] != DBNull.Value).Average(x => x.Field<dynamic>(columnName));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.  The reason why I declared the lambda at the top of the method is  simply because that's what JavaScript does: it hoist the inner function to the top of the containing function.  Secondly (again, this is coming from more of a JS background) I feel that letting someone else who might be reading your code that there's a closure as soon as possible helps readability.  Personally, I don't think having an IsNumeric extension method is the best bet, but I was exploring some new ground and wanted to test the waters a bit :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie you could make it a normal method too if you wanted to (isNumeric), but Extension methods are awesome, so why not :D.
you can declare the lambda outside your function, or inside. But in your case there is no reason to even have a lambda. Might as well just run the code

Comment: agreed, I don't think the lambda here serves any real useful function, and probably makes the code less readable.

Comment: 1. How is closing over the loop variable relevant? The posted code doesn't close over `row`.

Comment: 2. You can't have `const` fields with complex values, I think you meant `readonly`.

Comment: 3. Using `All()` instead of the loop would make the code even simpler.